# Webpage Forms found by Selenium double the number that exist - Python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using this webpage:
[ximera](https://ximera.osu.edu/mooculus/calculus3/multipleIntegrals/digInIntegralsOverTrivialRegions)

I am trying to get a list of all the input locations using this line:

```
answerBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']/div[1]/input[1]")
```

Then I am iterating through them and submitting the answers. However, when I look at the length of `answerBoxes` it is around 216 while when I do a search for the form tag on the webpage source it only returns 108 items (which matches the number of answers I have to input). Why are there duplicate form objects being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath matches extra `input` fields. Try more specific XPath to select required elements only:

```
answerBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[starts-with(@id, 'answer')]/div/input")
print(len(answerBoxes))
# 108
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you, didn't realize the "starts-with" parameter existed.